# Base-n digits for a given value

Tags: delphi, pascal

Here is the function I use to produce a UInt64 result from an array of digits and a base value.

```
function BaseNToInteger(const ABase: Cardinal; const ADigits: Array of Byte): UInt64;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to (Length(ADigits) - 1) do begin
    Result := Result + (ADigits[i] * Power(i, ABase));
  end;
end;
```

*[Please don't worry about the Power() function there; I have written my own that uses cardinals and produces UInt64 results.]*

This is the easy part.

Since my maths skills seems to have rusted over the years, the hard part with which I am struggling with are these:

1) For a given UInt64 value, how do I produce an ADigits array for a given base value (where base is > 1)?

2) How do I determine the length of the ADigits array for a given base value (where base is > 1) that will represent a given UInt64 value?

Comment: You don't need Power if you loop in reverse order (you will only multiply). For reverse operation (integer to base n), you will repeatedly divide by the base (remainder yields the successive digits). Maximum length is given by ceiling(log(2^64-1)/log(base)). The easiest is to fix once and for all the maximum possible length, which is 64 (obtained for base 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementation as functions with dynamic Arrays ...

```
uses math;

type
  TDigits = Array of Byte;    

Function BaseNToInteger(const Digits: TDigits; Base: Integer): Cardinal;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := High(Digits) DownTo Low(Digits) do
    Result := Base * Result + Digits[i];
end;

Function IntegerToBaseN(Nr: Cardinal; Base: Integer): TDigits;
var
  i: integer;
  function CeilAllways(const X: Extended): Integer;
  begin
    Result := Integer(Trunc(X));
    if Frac(X) >= 0 then
      Inc(Result);
  end;    
begin
  SetLength(Result, CeilAllways(ln(Nr) / ln(Base)));
  for i := Low(Result) to High(Result) do
  begin
    Result[i] := Nr mod Base;
    Nr := Nr div Base;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Following my preceding comment, here is a possibility (compiled but not tested)

```
unit BaseConv;

interface

type
   TDigits = array[0 .. 63] of uint32;

{ Recover number from digits, number of digits is in nd }
procedure ToInteger(var n: uint32; var digits: TDigits; nd, base: integer);

{ Compute digits in given base, number of digits is returned in nd }
procedure FromInteger(n: uint32; var digits: TDigits; var nd: integer; base: integer);

implementation

procedure ToInteger(var n: uint32; var digits: TDigits; nd, base: integer);
var i: integer;
begin
  n := 0;
  for i := nd - 1 downto 0 do n := base*n + digits[i];
end;

procedure FromInteger(n: uint32; var digits: TDigits; var nd: integer; base: integer);
begin
  nd := 0;
  repeat
    digits[nd] := n mod base;
    n := n div base;
    nd := nd + 1;
  until n = 0;
end;

end.
```